# why does multiprocessing work on 1 machine and not on another when the python configuration is the same

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyenv

I have python 3.8.6 installed on an older computer through pyenv. I just got a new laptop and installed python 3.8.6 by using pyenv.

This is the code that works on one machine and not on the other:

```
for i in range(12):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = sngl_quote, args=(tickergrab, return_dict))
    p.start()
    # wait 10 seconds or until process finishes
    p.join(10)
    # if thread is still active
    if p.is_alive():
        print('timed out on 10 sec limit, trying again...')
        p.terminate()
```

It fails when I check p.is_alive().
On the machine that works, this returns false.
On the machine that doesn't work, this returns true.
If I isolate the target function, it works in both cases, so the problem must be with multiprocessing.

I will try anything.

I think I must have something installed incorrectly, but don't know where to begin to find out. If this is the wrong place to ask this, can someone point me to another place to ask this question?

Thanks :)

Comment: Which operating systems?

Comment: So the process hasn't finished its work in 10 seconds on the failing machine? Should it take that long? Can you put logging into the called function to see what it is doing?

Comment: Guessing from your variable names I wonder if single_quote is making an HTTP or API request to get relevant data. That's where you need to look for the problem. I'm also intrigued to understand why retrying up to 12 times is going to help. If single_quote ran for more that 10s on the first iteration, it's likely to do the same on subsequent executions

Answer (score 1):

DarkKnight's comment got me looking in the right direction. The module I was using to make an API request had been upgraded to an httpx response, which meant that the response object was now a different class. So I had to modify my code in the area where I make the API request so that it looked for the appropriate type of response. It had to do with keeping my systems all up to date.